# How to trigger lambda function through another function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to run one lambda function, that would return a list of parameters. Based on the number of parameters I would like to trigger another lambda functions to finish the process individually (e.g. 100 independent sub-lambda function).

Would like to know how this be done? It would be great if there are some github settings? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options: first, call [Invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) using the AWS SDK for your language.

Second, use [Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/how-step-functions-works.html).

Third, write each parameter onto an SQS queue, and configure the second Lambda to be triggered by that queue. This is the approach that I'd use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I would like to know if Step Function would be cheaper than SQS.

But I guess I didn't ask this question specific enough. I would to set this up and run this functions by the beginning of the month. And I would like to setup like a single project - like the container way. How could I get this done? Thanks a lot

Comment: I think that SQS will be cheaper, but AWS publishes costs for each service, so you can compare. As for "How could I get this done," that's not a valid question for Stack Overflow. AWS publishes a lot of architecture documentation and sample code that can help you with that question.

Comment: I agree that they have done a lot of sample architecture. But it is too complicated as the same problem can be done in different ways.

Also I would like to finish one project by using multiple services, but it would be tough from a management perspective. Therefore I would like to seek for management advice at the same time.